# ERR for Score plot (PCA)

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

I am doing PCA in R and I got the result. But when I try to plot the first two principal components I get an error:

```
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: fill
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'GROUP' not found
```

Here is my code:

```
data = read.csv("pca_scores.csv", header = T)
data = data[, c(1:3)]
ggplot(data, aes(PC1, PC2)) +
       geom_point(aes(shape = Group)) +
       geom_text(aes(label = data$X)) +
       stat_ellipse(aes(fill = Group))
```

I knew the problem is the “Group”. I did not mention the group in the previous code. But I really don't know how to change it

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHgrj.png

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Pictures of data are not very helpful. If you don't have a group, just use `geom_point()` rather than `geom_point(aes(shape = Group))`.

Comment: Are you getting both Warning and Error of is it just one thing? And yes provide a sample of that `"pca_scores.csv"`

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @MrFlick, you should always provide sample data; a screenshot of your `data.frame` is *not* useful.

That aside, you can try this:

```
require(tidyverse);
data %>%
    mutate(Group = gsub("\\(.+\\)$", "", X)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(PC1, PC2)) +
        geom_point(aes(shape = Group)) +
        geom_text(aes(label = X)) +
        stat_ellipse(aes(fill = Group))
```

A few comments:

1. You don't need to use `data$` inside `aes()`; just refer to the relevant column directly.
2. I've added a `Group` column, which strips the `"(PubChem: ...)"` part from `X`.
3. Keep in mind that `stat_ellipse` will only draw an ellipse if there are `>3` points.